# Google Sheets vlookup based on multiple criteria with wildcards

Tags: google-sheets-formula, wildcard, criteria

I'm trying to extend a gs vlookup formula with a 2nd criteria.

This formula works fine with 1 criteria in column A.
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(VLOOKUP("*"&A2:A&"*",sheet2!C:D,2,FALSE), ""))

But I would like to extend the formula with a 2nd (OR) criteria .
That sould somehow look like this:
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(VLOOKUP("*"&A2:A&"*" OR "*"&B2:B&"*",sheet2!C:D,2,FALSE), ""))
(The fomula shoud check if one of the 2 criterias (in column A or B) matches with column C on sheet2 and return the value from D on sheet2)

Is this even possible with a fomula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula seems to do what you're looking for, placed in C2:

```
=ArrayFormula(
  IFNA(  VLOOKUP(A2:A,Sheet2!C:D,2,0),
    IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B,Sheet2!C:D,2,0),"no match")))
```

I think there are several other ways of doing this, but I went with what you'd started with.

I haven't added error checking yet, for blank rows, etc., to keep it straightforward.

[image]

Comment: thnx, this works very good. Are the several other ways you mentioned by queries?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  I really like using queries for most things.  If I put one together, I'll add another answer here.  Glad it helped... Please apply the checkmark to this answer, if appropriate, to help others with similar questions.